# Docker Compose - executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have the below Dockerfile for rest api service along with a Docker compose file for the infrastructure setup locally.

I am able to build the image from Dockerfile successfully. However, the `docker-compose up` brings the below error.

Error:

```
ERROR: for api_rest_api_1  Cannot start service rest_api: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "app": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for rest_api  Cannot start service rest_api: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "app": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

File: .env

```
PORT=8081
GIN_MODE=release

PMA_PORT=3306
PMA_HOST=mysql
PMA_USER=root
PMA_PASSWORD=example
PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

File: Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.18.3-alpine3.16 AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# pre-copy/cache go.mod for pre-downloading dependencies and only redownloading them in subsequent builds if they change
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .
RUN go build -v -o /usr/local/bin/app ./.

FROM alpine:3.16

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin

COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/app /usr/local/bin/

CMD ["app"]
```

File: docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  rest_api:
    networks:
      - api-network
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mysql
      - phpmyadmin
  redis:
    networks:
      - api-network
    image: "redis:7.0.0-alpine3.16"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:8.0.29"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - api-network
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - api-network
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    env_file:
      - .env

networks:
  api-network:
```

Comment: Try to change your entrypoint with an explicit relative path: `./app`.